# Why is the Datacontex not updated?

Tags: c#, uwp, datacontext

[image]

When the selection is changed, the values of the form should be updated but is only updated the name of the task.

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"  Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Path=NameTask}" />
```

the texBlock of the button duedate

```
<Button Name="Calendar_Button" Click="calendar_button"  Background="Transparent">
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <fa:FontAwesome Grid.Column="0" Icon="Calendar" FontSize="20" Foreground="Fuchsia" ></fa:FontAwesome>
                    <TextBlock  Name="DueDateTexblock" Foreground="White"  Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=FormatDate}" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>

                </Grid>
            </Button>

<Button Name="reminder_button" Click="reminder_button_Click">

                <Grid>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <fa:FontAwesome Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Icon="ClockOutline" FontSize="20" Foreground="Fuchsia" ></fa:FontAwesome>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding Path=Reminder }" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>

                </Grid>
            </Button>
```

The method when the selection changed

```
 private void task_list_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        task = task_list.SelectedItem as TaskTodo;
        this.DataContext = task;
        TaskForm.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

I did a method for see when the datacontext is changed.
so the data context of the button where is the texblock with
the DueDate just is changed a one time.

What i want is all the values, take the actual task selected

Comment: What do the bindings look like for the other controls?

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

This is how  I solved  the problem for now.
updating the datacontext of each button.

```
 //update the values of the button from taskform
 Calendar_Button.DataContext = task;
 reminder_button.DataContext = task;
```